# Finding .NET specification

Tags: c#, java, .net, jakarta-ee

Are there a public set of specifications for a given .NET release?

In our product development, we have used large parts of Java EE since J2EE 1.3 for some of the products. Even though the platform is large, it has always been easy to find what is included in a given release. Both Java SE and Java EE are a set of specifications. Several vendors offers implementations of the specifications. This works remarkably good.

I'm now discussing with a college about a .NET solution for another product. Frankly I'm quite frustrated of how hard it is to find whats included in a given .NET release. My initial assumption was that C# + CIL is roughly Java SE and .NET Java EE. However, I can't find information about e.g. container managed transactions in .NET or if ISS is a part of .NET or not. If not, how does ISS interact with .NET? Can an alternative server be used?

Please help me in directions to a Java EE spec similar description of .NET.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_1.1 - there is a start to the changes here

Comment: [C# Language Specification 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), version 1.0 is here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30940 - do a Google search and you can probably find the others.

Comment: You may also consider looking at ECMA-335, the specification of CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might not be easy to find a single consistent specification, but there are various resources with the information you are looking for, such as:

- [An overview of the .Net Framework (4.5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw4w595w.aspx)
- [Roadmap for .Net Framework (4.5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj160347.aspx)
- [Quick Technology Finder for the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63bf39c2.aspx) (a list of tech and features)

For each version of the framework, you've also got the **[What's new pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx)**. This link is for version 4.5, but if you select "Other Versions" from just below the title, you'll get info about new developments previous versions of the framework.